# Drools- Validating multiple conditions on set of data and getting failed condition

Tags: drools

I have a list of dates, let's say 10 dates. Now, I have to apply a set of rules among these elements to find matching set of 4 dates that satisfies all rules.

Assuming following are the rules. How do I iterate this in drools and find the four valid dates among provided set of lets say 5 given dates. Also lets say if any of them are not satisfied, how do I implement the condition why its failed (as we can't do if else in drools.)

date2> date1 + (6W - 4D)

date3> date2 + (4W - 4D)

date4> date3 + (6M - 4D)

date4> date1 + (4Y - 4D)

I am eventually looking for something like, 
provided_date1, provided_date2, provided_date4, provided_date5 satisfies this condition.

Or none of provided dates satisfies them because condition 2 is not satisfied.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use temporal reasoning over the dates. See the docs for that https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.6.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#_temporal_reasoning